# How to call a function from inside an emacs org-mode octave source block

Tags: emacs, octave, org-mode

Setup: Emacs 27.2/Org-mode 9.5/Octave 6.4/Win10

I have an octave source block that calls the ODE45 function to do integration on some data (see below).

```
+BEGIN_SRC octave :output results
%Times
tdat = 1:1:100; 
% Initial Conditions
m0 =150000;g0 =1.51;V0=150;H0=1000;X0=0;
y0=[m0 H0 X0 V0 g0];
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-7,'AbsTol',1e-10*ones(1,5));
% Call ODE45
[t,y] = ode45('UseDyn',tdat,y0,options);
% plot and store chart.png
plot(y(:,3),y(:,2));
print -dpng chart.png;
ans = "chart.png"
#+END_SRC
```

It needs to call the function UseDyn.m which contains the initial data and equations to be integrated by ODE45.

```
function [ydot]=UseDyn(t,y);
  (four lines of equations)
end
```

I have tried inserting the equation block to be processed three ways:

1. its own source block preceding this one. Executed prior to the main code block.
2. into the main source block prior to the main code. Executed as one large block.
3. into the main source block after the main code.

None of those methods worked. Octave does not see required function nor is it created as a separate file in the source directory.

My octave setup in my init file is as follows with org-babel set to (octave t):

```
(require 'ob-octave)
(add-to-list 'load-path "c:/Users/xxxx/Octave/mingw64/bin")
```

Can someone tell me how to properly call an external function from inside an octave source block? Is my org-mode setup insufficient?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be to use `:noweb yes` and have a src block for the `UseDyn` function.  Give that src block a name, e.g. `usedyn`. Then include that function into the main src block with `<<usedyn>>` at the start of the block.

You might not need or wish to put `UseDyn` in quotes when calling `ode45`.